# Artifact correction in spatstat for biological cells point patterns

Tags: r, spatstat

I am using `spatstat` to analyze biological cells (dependencies, interactions, etc.) with their centers to generate point patterns. However, I realize the artifact caused due to their sizes in 2D. What are the best ways to correct such artifacts when using K/L, G- functions, etc.? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still a research question (i.e. a topic of research in statistical methodology).